# Sinch display video on incoming call

Tags: android, sinch

Is it possible to display video of incoming call before call.answer() function is called in video app to app calling ? (like Google Duo does for example).
In your android example sinch.android.rtc.sample.video.push there is a comment "Display some kind of icon showing it's a video call" in IncomingCallActivity but this function is not called if you didn't answer a call.

```
    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackAdded(Call call) {
        // Display some kind of icon showing it's a video call

        addRemoteView();
    }
```

Comment: "In your example" - in what example?

Comment: sinch.android.rtc.sample.video.push sample from their Sinch SDK for android

Comment: No, thats not possible